# Alternative of using HTML markups under calculated field in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-list, calculated-column, html

I have a calculated filed column in one document library which used to display and Image icon with a hyperlink attached to this. But it seems Microsoft has stopped supporting this feature. [Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields)

Can Some suggest me some alternative or quick fix to resolve this **production issue**. Any help will be appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JSLink to resolve this issue.Here you can find sample example.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd/sourcecode?fileId=109730&pathId=1836828232